# % of complete by high level grouping in PowerBI?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and looking for any help I can get. I'll try to keep this short and to the point:

My data set for Power BI is just a big list containing (but not limited to) users, training courses, training programs, and completion statuses.

A training program is comprised of multiple training courses.

All I'm trying to do is put together a table that shows me a training program completion % for each user and which training courses they have yet to complete. So for example, Training Program 1 is comprised of 10 training courses. If a user has completed courses 1-7, then their Program Completion % would be 70%. Then 3 courses would be displayed as incomplete, courses 8-10.

I've tried numerous DAX measures to accomplish this and they either only work partially or don't work at all.

Happy to provide a test .pbix file for context and/or an example of the DAX measures I'm using so far, but posting without them initially so I don't confuse anyone trying to help.

Any help is appreciated, but if this is the wrong forum or folks are just unable to help, that's fine too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: pbix file would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, here is a possible solution.

Assuming your data is looking like this. The granularity is each user and courses of the training program he is enrolled in. Here let's call this table ProgramEnrollment.

[image: table]

Although not mandatory, it is a good idea to factor out Users and Training Programs into separate dimension tables, and form a star schema.

[image: schema]

Then, the desired ratio can be calculated in a measure with formula below.

```
Program Completion % = 
VAR NumCompleted = CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( ProgramEnrollment ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( ProgramEnrollment, User, TrainingProgram ),
    ProgramEnrollment[Status] = "Completed"
)
VAR NumAllCourses = CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( ProgramEnrollment ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( ProgramEnrollment, User, TrainingProgram )
)
RETURN IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( User[User] ) &&
    HASONEVALUE( TrainingProgram[Training Program] ),
    DIVIDE ( NumCompleted + 0, NumAllCourses )
)
```